# How to detect all beacons around?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

hello i have just started working on Beacons. I am able to detect beacons of specific type depending on the UUID. But my requirements is to detect all the beacons around. irrespective of the different manufacturer like (I have) Estimote, Blue Cat, minue, and few other. i have gone thru many blogs but unable to find the right solution.

Any reference or suggestions are highly appreciated.

Comment: You can't. You can only scan for a specific UUID (up to 20 different at the same time).

Answer (score 1):

To be able to detect all of them using iBeacon standard (Core Location) in a single region, you'd need to edit UUID of all your beacons and set them for the same value. So that's possible only if all of your beacons have an SDK allowing for UUID changing. Estimote and BlueCats allow that for sure, I don't know about Minew.

Cheers.